# Unity Javascript GUI.Button shows up twice

Tags: unity, 2d, javascript, gui

Hi I have created a simple menu in Unity but I wanted to create my own style for colour/fonts.

However for some reason it prints each button twice to the screen, once with my custom style, and once without.

this is the code I have used:

```
if(menu){


if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2 - 50, Screen.height/2, 100, 30), "Start Game", customGuiStyle)){

Application.LoadLevel ("Level 1");
}


if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2 - 50, Screen.height/2 + 30, 100, 30), "Options", customGuiStyle)){


menu = false;
options = true;
}


if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2 - 50, Screen.height/2 + 90, 100, 30), "Quit", customGuiStyle)){


Application.Quit();
}
}
```

I have no idea why it is showing two texts, heres a screen shot of exactly what I mean...[image]

Comment: Add more information about where it is placed OnGUI? Update? What have you tried and with what results?